# Using "@" in regular expression with VB.NEt

Tags: regex, vb.net

Assuming I have to check if "@" exists on a given string - should I use back slash before or not? So far I found they're both working for me, but I'm not sure if it always works on any Windows host (this is part of a VB.NET application that has to work world-wide)

The string:  `Hello @world`

Pattern1: `Hello @world`

Pattern 2: `Hello \@world`

Which one should I use to get the most precise matching? pattern1 or pattern2?

I work with VB.NET on VS2010 (.NET FW 3.5)

Thank you

Comment: Where exactly are you using a back-slash? Can you post code that shows your question more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

`@` is not a special regex character, at least not in VB.NET. Which means that both patterns are pretty much the same, and you can use whichever you prefer. Although for readability sake you probably should stick to the pattern without backslash.

You can find complete list of special regex characters in .NET [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: ...but please prefer the no-backslash version.  Why pollute your regexes with more backslashes if you don't have to?

Comment: @AlanMoore. fair enough, added the remark to the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to leave this option on Regex engine. Just use its [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function. It will escape the necessary things.